# one socket to reach multiple addresses

Tags: go

I have to send an UDP packet to each host of the network, say N hosts.

My current C implementation it's pretty simple:

- open an UDP socket
- use `sendto` over the same socket for every host

With Go I have `net.Conn` ( Connection ), not sockets.

How can I send UDP packets to different hosts using only one fd ?

As now I have to close and open a `net.Conn` N times.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: If you're working with UDP, you have a UDPConn which has methods to write to a specific address. Can you show an example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [net.ListenUDP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenUDP) to create a UDP socket with a desired local port (or 0 to get an available port assigned). This will give you a [net.UDPConn](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn) which has [WriteTo](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.WriteTo) and [ReadFrom](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.ReadFrom) methods (equivalent to `sendto` and `recvfrom`). The difference between WriteTo/ReadFrom and WriteToUDP/ReadFromUDP is that the former implement the generic [PacketConn](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#PacketConn) interface, while the latter are UDP-specific, which can reduce the amount of casting if you know you're always using UDP.